# DataSet.StorageType in Vuforia SDK

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, vuforia, unityscript

i try to create virtual button in run time, but there is a note said that the database must be deactivated before creating a virtual button.
So, I try to deactivated my data set, but i got a problem, the dataset always return null.
Is there anything wrong if i write the code something like this:

```
myDataSet.Load("Assets/StreamingAssets/QCAR/TA_5109100114",  DataSet.StorageType.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE);
```

Comment: please show your code (what have you tried) and explain what goes wrong.

Comment: @Renaissance
this is my code and it's explanation.
Thank you very much for your respond.

The code : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107928841/Vuforia/ObjectLoaderManager.cs

the explanation : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/107928841/Vuforia/!READ_ME_FIRST.txt

Comment: I suggest you add the relevant code to you post

Comment: @Renaissance i'm sory i don't understand what you meant,
can you give me more specific?
I'm so sorry before,

Comment: I mean copy your code from the link in your comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to load a Dataset from assets folder, you should use the same storage type you are using, but the path is incorrect.
You should put only the name of the .xml file, like this:

```
myDataSet.Load("YourDataSetXmlFile.xml",  DataSet.StorageType.STORAGE_APPRESOURCE);
```

use absolute path only with  DataSet.StorageType.STORAGE_ABSOLUTE.

Comment: what should you do if you want to load the file from the cache?